# making up your F (Green's theorem)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Use Green's Theorem to find the areas enclosed by curve $$C: 2x^2+3y^2=2y$$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can someone tell me how to make up $F.\,\,\,$

Comment: Green's Theorem would only make such a simple question more complicated.

Comment: Obviously we can use the formula of area of ellipse but how do we find F such that we can use green

Comment: If you use green, instead of calculation of area of ellipse (easy), you need to calculate circumference of ellipse(impossible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to complete the square. This should be the "obvious" thing to do.

Write $2x^2 + 3y^2 - 2y + 1/3 = 2x^2 + 3(y-1/3)^2 = 1/3$. Apply a change of variables $x \rightarrow u= \sqrt{2}x$ and $y\rightarrow v = \sqrt{3}(y-1/3)$. Note that the determinant of the Jacobian is $1/\sqrt{6}$ and proceed by integration to get $\text{Area} = 1/\sqrt{6}\cdot (\pi\cdot (1/3)) = \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{6}}$.

Note that Green is not necessary here. If you must, $\oint_{C}\; -y/2\; dx + x/2\; dy$ shall do the trick (at least in theory), (why?), where we must "pullback" $dx$ and $dy$. But this will give you an elliptic integral, which is computationally far uglier than computing the area directly.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your last paragraph please. Because the whole point of the question is to use green (not trying to be rude). I know you don't have to use it.

Comment: Do the change of variables as above and re-parameterize to get $\oint_{C}\; -y/2\; dx + x/2\; dy = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\; \frac{\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}{2\cdot \sqrt{3}^2} = \pi/3$. Just recall to adjust by the determinant, which is constant, of the Jacobian.

Comment: If you insist on re-parameterising directly: complete the square and write $t \rightarrow 1/\sqrt{3}\cdot (\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{\sin(t)+1/3}{\sqrt{3}})$ and integrate over $[0, 2\pi]$.